# Prevent FocusEvents when Component is not focused

Tags: java, swing, focus

I have the following sample-code:

```
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SampleFocus extends JFrame {

  public SampleFocus(String titel) {
    setTitle(titel);
    JTextField txtField1 = new JTextField("default-click");
    JTextField txtField2 = new JTextField("alternative-Text");
    JTextField txtField3 = new JTextField("own diaolog textfield");

    JTextArea dummyLabel = new JTextArea(10, 20);
    dummyLabel.setText("empty textarea, which is focusable");

    setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(txtField1);
    add(dummyLabel);
    add(txtField2);

    JDialog altDialog = new JDialog(this);
    altDialog.add(txtField3);
    altDialog.setVisible(true);
    altDialog.pack();

    FocusAdapter myFocusListner = new FocusAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        if (e.getComponent() instanceof JTextField) {
          System.out.println("gained for TextField: "
                             + ((JTextField) e.getComponent()).getText());
        } else {
          System.out.println("gained for component: " + e.getComponent());
        }
      }
    };

    txtField1.addFocusListener(myFocusListner);
    txtField2.addFocusListener(myFocusListner);
    txtField3.addFocusListener(myFocusListner);

    // dummyLabel.addFocusListener(myFocusListner);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new SampleFocus("FocusListener  - sample");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

When I switch from the Frame to the dialog I get the proper event. When I switch back to the Frame I get as well the proper FocusEvents. My problem is, that when I switch back, I get as well the FocusEvents for components which I am not interested in.

e.g.

Select 'default-click' ==> Dialog/Textfield ==> Frame/'empty textarea'

Result: I get a FocusGained-Event for 'default-click' although the component has NOT the focus.

Desired Result: Either

- Component 'default-click' does not get the FocusEvent OR
- distinguish if the component really received the Event properly (e.g. I could have clicked into it as well)

Workaround I found:

Attach to the JTextArea as well a FocusListener. Problem is, that this would mean, I need to attach to ALLLL of my components a Listener. Which is hardly possible. Any ideas?

Any ideas how to get the result?

Thx LeO

Answer (score 0):

Its working as intended.
You select "default-click". It gains focus.
You select Dialog. Frame and "default-click" loses focus.
You select Text area. Now, things becomes interesting. Dialog loses focus. Frame gets focus. "default-click" also gains focus, because he had it when Frame was active. And then "default-click" loses focus, textarea gains focus (because you clicked on text area).

Try combine focusGained and focusLost events.

Or tell me more what are you trying to accomplish, maybe I can help.

Comment: Lost and Gain - maybe. But the main problem I have, I want e.g. a Label which displays the current resp. last focused JTextField (to display the properties). So, I can set it to 'default-click' => 'own diaolog textfield' fine as soon as it is gained. But I don't wanna set it to 'default-click' once more, cause this has not any longer any kind of focus. The label should remain with the properties of 'own dialog textfield'. And focus-lost+focus-gained are in my understanding not necessarily combined due to timing-issues. So, a code relying on a certain order of the Events is not what I want.

Comment: Order of focus events has **certain** order - one component loses focus, then another component gains focus. When you activate(click on it, alt+tab from another window etc) window  (Frame, Dialog), one of its components always get focus. If window is not new and had focus before, focus will be returned to component who had it before.

Comment: The label should remain with the properties of 'own dialog textfield' umm, but dialog and text field in it doesn't have focus either...

Comment: I have a component in one Frame which displays any kind of properties (=e.g. JTextArea) from my own component (=e.g. JTextField). From the user perspective I would expect, that as soon as I have selected the own component (=JTextField) and click into the properties-area (=JTextArea), I still wanna have the properties from the last selected selfwritten-component (=JTextField) AND NOT the properties from any previously selected component anywhere else which is focused randomly [?].

Comment: Well anyway, I don't wanna discuss it tooo detailed. I have my idea about the design and asking if anybody has an idea for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found the workaround was to check in the focusGained-method if the current component is in an own JDialog and if previous component was a JTextField in a JFrame. If so, then I memorize the gained focused component, change the focus to another component and when I receive a focusLost I request it back to the previously memorized component.

Some kind of hack, but it works.... If there are any better ideas, I am interested in ...